# Http url query rating highest

Tags: google-places-api

Is there a way to modify the http url to additionally query for all resturants in Sidney with the keyword cruise with the highest rating resturant first (element 0) in the JSON object

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=1500&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided during runtime to sort the JSONarray objects by storing them in ArrayList, use Collection.sort(), and restoring back the sorted Arraylist to a JSONarray.